# My boyfriend pays my rent + utilities. I don't have a job. Do i consider that as income?

Tags: united-states, gift-tax, rent

My boyfriend gives me money (634) every month to pay my rent + water, & pays my electric bill w/his credit card. Sometimes he gives a check to the landlord for rent + water. Do i consider/report any of it as my income? I am unemployed, and the only way i pay for anything is by getting gifts from other people. FEMA is asking me for my income, and i don't know what to put. Do i even file taxes (I haven't)? I've only had this arrangement for a little over a year.

Comment: I assume by FEMA you mean the Federal Emergency Management Agency of the US Department of Homeland Security, so tagged as US.

Answer (score 4):

What country - U.S.?

Your boyfriend paying your rent would be a gift (unless it's in exchange for goods or services, which it sounds like it isn't), and he'd be responsible for all relevant gift tax return (Form 709) filings. However, the gift tax exclusion is $17,000 for 2023, so as long as he gives you less than that this year he doesn't need to report the gifts.

Regarding FEMA asking you for your income, you should follow their requirements for income reporting. If that means you need to file a tax return with $0 income and $0 taxes, you should do that (silly as that would be).

Comment: There could also be income from any unemployment payments from the state.

Answer (score 2):

Is your housing arrangement in your name, e.g. a lease? If you have a lease, or even month-to-month, and it is in your boyfriend's name, it doesn't matter whether he lives there or not. None of the payments he makes (rent, electricity, water, or other utilities) would be considered as your income.

If your housing is in YOUR name, and your boyfriend pays for everything in cash, it might not be considered income. Doesn't sound like that is the case though, as you mentioned that he pays for some of your housing and utilities costs by check or credit card. I still doubt that the money your boyfriend pays would be considered income, which I'll explain next.

You are responsible for utilities. I used [estimates from ApartmentGuides.com](https://www.apartmentguide.com/blog/how-much-do-utilities-cost-in-a-studio-apartment/) for a 1 bedroom / studio apartment. (I tried energy.gov and U.S. Energy Information Administration, but [they average over all residential customers](https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/detail.php?id=46276) which includes houses so their estimates were too high for your case.)

For electricity without heating and cooling, they estimated about $65 per month assuming you use appliances or an electric oven. If you use A/C for four months in summer, that would be about $35 per month. If you use electricity or gas for heat in the winter, that's $50 during those month. The A/C seems low and the non-heat and A/C seem high but they probably average out okay. Water should be a lot less, especially for one person. If you use a dishwasher, it could be as much as $50.

- Your rent is $634;
- Water is $50;
- Electricity is $65
- Heat  &  A/C  are (($50 * 8) + ($35 * 4) )/ 12 =  $45

So, (634 + 50 + 65 + 45) * 12 = $9528 for a year. Let's round up to $10,000 for late charges, errors, etc.

The federal gift tax applies to all gifts of property by an individual during the year. "Property" can be cash, forgiving a debt, land, whatever. The federal gift tax is paid by the person who does the giving (your boyfriend), not by the recipient (you).

This won't be an issue, because the [gift tax exclusion for 2023 is $17,000](https://www.kiplinger.com/taxes/gift-tax-exclusion). If your boyfriend gives you more than $17,000 in 2023, then he has to file a federal gift tax return, IRS Form 709, for the amount greater than $17,000. Since **$10,000 is less than $17,000**, he won't have to file or pay any gift tax. You would not be liable for taxes as the recipient of the money.